# Modulus Inequalities

Tags: inequality, summation, modules, real-numbers, square-numbers

I'm trying to prove the following inequality

> $|\frac{|(x|x|-|x|)|}{|x|}| \leq 1-|x|$

This is the calculation that I'm doing;

> $|\frac{|(x|x|-|x|)|}{|x|}|= \frac{|x|^2-|x|}{x} \le \frac{|x|^2+|x|}{x}= |x|+1$

How should I proceed from here?

Comment: The inequality as written is not true in general, it is only true if $0 \leq x \leq 1$. I assume you want the inequality to be the other way around as then it is universally true. Regarding how to prove it, as you are working with real numbers, the easiest way is probably to split into different cases and then prove it for each seperately.

Comment: @fishbane this is a part of a big solution. The domain is $\Omega=B(0,1)$ so yes the domain for x is what you said. But If that's the case, how can I get this result?

Comment: did you write the inequality correctly? Why would you not just simplify the LHS to $|x - 1|$?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can start from this
$$ \left|\frac{(| x|x| - |x||)}{|x|}\right| = \left|\left( \left|\frac{x|x|-|x|}{|x|}\right|\right)\right| = \left| \left|x-1\right|\right| =| 1-x| \le 1-|x|.
$$
Last inequality hold because of $x \in (0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you @niccolo